# Could a young dragon be coerced into captivity?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dragons

My players and I are running Sunless Citadel(5e). Some of you may know it - the white dragon wyrmling was captured by kobolds and worshipped by them.

> 1 Then it escaped to another part of the citadel and is hiding out there.

The module says, and I quote:

> The wyrmling finds her current situation superior to her station as the kobolds' pet. She is hostile to those who enter this chamber.

However, my players were very slow and methodical about this, and I didn't want this to be another bum-rush fight, so I sort of let them finagle their way into the room, using some dead rats they had collected earlier as feed for the dragon. Now the dragon eats, and the player is gently sort of trying to get it to come back with her.

I'm honestly not sure what to do. On one hand, the players have been extremely slow and patient, and I feel like I should reward that sort of dedication.
On the other hand, the dragon figured out that they were working for the kobolds, and is naturally distrustful.

Why would the dragon go with them?
It only has an intelligence of 5 - it can barely even speak draconic.  As such, you would think that it would fall for such traps, because it literally doesn't know any better.

Would a dragon go with them, or would it steadfastly refuse?

Comment: Note that *"what do you think?"* type questions aren't suited for this site as they are, in essence, asking for opinions. Please consider rewording this in such a way as to ask about the actual problem rather than asking for opinions.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?